# How to convert WHERE IN clause with multiple values to RegExp or Like

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like, where-in

I want to convert this:

```
SELECT id,songTitle,artistName, trackId
FROM songs
WHERE (songTitle, artistName) IN (('come together', 'the beatles'),('all the small things', 'blink-182'))
```

To something like this but I don't know the right syntax:

```
SELECT id,songTitle,artistName, trackId
FROM songs
WHERE (songTitle, artistName) IN LIKE (('%come together%', '%the beatles%'),('%all the small things%', '%blink-182%'))
```

Except I'm searching 100s of more songs at once.  We could use REGEXP too I just don't know the right syntax for either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `WHERE (a,b) IN ((1,2), ...)` is very poorly optimized.
- Leading wild cards in `LIKE` prevents use of an index.
- You can't do the construct you attempted.

So, performance aside, let's look at how to perform the task:

```
WHERE ( songTitle LIKE '%come together%' AND artistName LIKE '%the beatles%')
   OR ( .... )
   OR ...
```

Sorry, there is no short cut.

REGEXP can't help *in this case*.

`FULLTEXT` indexing is something to consider, but I don't see that it would help in this example.